# How to predict the output without a computer?

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point

Consider the following python code.

```
s = 0.0
for i in range(10):
  s += 0.1
print(s == 1.0)
```

Will the output of the above be true ?

This was a past paper question of a python written exam paper. I know the output would be **False**. I know that because I checked it on python interpreter. But how someone can tell whether output is True or False without a computer ? For example if I changed the range to 5 and last line to `print(s == 0.5)` output would be True. So how to predict the output (without a computer nearby)? (PS: I know the output was False because of the floating point representation of the computer.)

Comment: This looks like a theoretical question which tests your understanding on how computer stores floats. I would say some textbook on Computer Arithmetic would be a right place to start. Though only place you would encounter these kind of problems would be some technical interview, so better approach is to look for "how to ace a tech interview" material online / book store.

Comment: The output is not necessarily false, because the Python documentation does not strictly regulate how floating-point arithmetic behaves in Python implementations. Many use IEEE-754 binary64 with round-to-nearest-ties-to-even, but this is not required.

Comment: Once the floating-point format and arithmetic is determined, there is not generally an easy way to predict the result of various operations other than by actually doing the arithmetic. Whether the rounding errors that occur in a sequence of operations happen to cancel and produce the same final result as real-number arithmetic is not easily predictable in general. Sometimes various number-theoretic considerations may produce useful patterns in special cases, but, for the most part, you find the answer by actually doing the arithmetic. There is no general shortcut.

Comment: Did the question ask for a discussion answer or a simple binary true-false?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan As I mentioned the question was "Will the output of the above be true ?"

Comment: I was trying to find out the context. Is this the sort of exam where one is expected to justify an answer, or one where just writing "No" would be sufficient?